# Library to temporarily modify (core) Ruby modules

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rubygems

I once came across a Ruby library (I'm not sure it was ever packaged as a gem) that allowed you to conveniently apply temporary modifications to Ruby modules. These modifications would only be active within blocks executed within a 'with' declaration, like:

```
with(modifications) do
  [interesting stuff requiring the modifications]
end
```

It made sure you didn't need to permanently pollute (core) modules just to get something special done in certain places.

As a specific example of what I want to do: I would like to define an 'in?' method on Fixnum, so users of an internal DSL can type:

```
if value.in? [12, 16, 27, 28]
  [do something interesting]
end
```

I would wrap the DSL evaluation with a 'with' method and I wouldn't have to pollute Fixnum with this in? method. I know this isn't too hard to do, but there are probably some dark corners and I had the impression this library was very convenient for this purpose.

Does anyone know the name of this library I am looking for? I seem to recall it was something like 'plusplus', but Google doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came across the answer: the [Rewrite gem by raganwald](https://github.com/raganwald/rewrite). Unfortunately, it was only a proof of concept and not much has come of it. It works by parsing the Ruby into an AST, mangling the tree and converting the result back to Ruby. This is of course incredibly powerful, but raganwald never got around to introducing general tools to implement specific manglings, and creating a new one is, in his own words, ‘torturous’.

Implementing the `in?` method on String would mean searching the AST for the specific S-expression that represents calling `in?` on a String and converting that to a different method call; probably an `in?(string, args)` in the local namespace. This soon turns into the problem of static type checking, lest you interpret every `in?` as a `String#in?`.

Comment: That [GitHub repository link](https://github.com/raganwald/rewrite) is broken, and the repo is not on [raganwald’s GitHub profile](https://github.com/raganwald). But rewrite does have a [RubyForge page](http://rewrite.rubyforge.org/), and it is still a [RubyGem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rewrite), though it was last updated on 18 July 2008 on both of those pages.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. this sounds like a proposal for what might be included in Ruby 2. 
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of method replacement approached (alias_method, module inclusion and so on) so I provide an abstract code:

```
def with_modification   
   replace_method # for instance, alias_method

   yield    

   replace_method_back 
end
```

It will work. Of course, you can enhance this DSL by providing a description of what exactly you want to change in order to make this method flexible, it's completely up to you.

Comment: A trivial implementation certainly isn't hard, but before you know it, you'll be extending it with proper handling of name clashes, exception handling and handling of other complications that aren't a problem, or even obvious, at first. Although fun, it's a waste of my employers's time when I am fairly certain I've once seen a library that was already pretty mature in providing this functionality.